# Which one is preferred: $r2^m$ or $2^m r$?

Tags: notation, article-writing

Which is preferable to write: $r2^m$ or $2^m r$?

Comment: That really depends on context, but probably the second one is used more often.

Comment: I'd usually go with $2^{m}r$ or $2^m \cdot r$ but $r2^m$ is acceptable

Comment: Placing this question "on hold" as primarily opinion-based answers the question: namely that there are arguments both ways. But this was not obvious to the OP at the time of posting. The OP will hopefully have gained some useful information before the question is deleted.

Comment: If $m$ is at least temporarily fixed, and you’re interested in multiples of $2^m$, then $r2^m$ is more natural. A generalization of the principle that numerical factors are written before symbolic ones would suggest writing $2^mr$, though this can be unwieldy if instead of $m$ you have a long, complicated exponent. Individuals’ aesthetic preferences also come into play. There really is no rule here.

Answer (score 3):

Usually $2^m r$ is more preferable.

Comment: I agree with this, but I'm not sure why I feel this way. May be because (known) numeral constants should come before the variables/unknowns?

Comment: @ Jyrki Lahtonen Of course, it depends on the form of variables. In the end it is a matter of taste. Tastes differ. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it matters too much if it is typed but if it is handwritten then I prefer $r2^m$ for the reasons pointed out by Shobhit. When typing also, I would prefer $r2^m$ if the exponent became too big. Typing $r2^{a + bc + d + efg}$ is clearer and more aesthetically pleasing than $2^{a + bc + d + efg}r$.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would write literal constants first followed by variables in alphabetical order.

e.g. $256pq^2r$

So, using this scheme, the preferred syntax would be: $2^mr$

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is: in a product, write the numerals before the letters; and write the constants before the variables. Here, the exponent $m$ complicates the issue, and we would usually write $x\mathrm e^x$ in preference to $\mathrm e^xx$. (However, $\mathrm e^xy$ is arguably as natural as $y\mathrm e^x$.) In the present example, we are probably thinking of $2^mr$ as a generic form for $r$, $2r$, $4r$, and so on; so the $2^m$ tends to inherit the first position.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that there is no general preference, some will prefer
the first while the other prefer the second.

Answer (score -1):

I think $r2^m$ is usually used, because if we write r at the end it is sometimes confused with $2^{mr}$

Comment: $r2^m$ is also sometimes confused with $r^{2^m}$. What do you think? :-)

Comment: @PSTikZ No its is not, because when we are doing hard and fast math we could confuse it with $2^{mr}$ but to confuse $r2^m$ with $r^{2^m}$ .I would just say wow.

Comment: :-) Maybe $r^{2m}$.

Comment: @PSTikZ well you are just pushing it. The OP asked for a way which will depend person to person, well this is what i like. If you do too, then just vote this up.